# How to write a comparator for SimpleObjectProperty<Date>

Tags: java, comparator, comparable

I've tried the following, and neither work:

```
    public static Comparator<ModelDefects> sortFirstFoundDateAscending() {
        return new Comparator<ModelDefects>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ModelDefects o1, ModelDefects o2) {
                return o1.getFirstFoundDate() - o2.getFirstFoundDate();
            }
        };
    }
```

```
    public static Comparator<ModelDefects> sortFirstFoundDateAscending() {
        return new Comparator<ModelDefects>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ModelDefects o1, ModelDefects o2) {
                return o1.getFirstFoundDate().compareTo(o2.getFirstFoundDate());
            }
        };
    }
```

Also tried the `<` operator via an `if` statement.  These didn't work either.  Tonnes of searching online did not reveal the answer to me.

First Found Date and its methods are defined as so:

```
//Declaration:
    private SimpleObjectProperty<Date> firstfounddate;

//Initialisation in Constructor:
    this.firstfounddate = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();


//First Found Date
    public Object getFirstFoundDate() {
        return firstfounddate.get();
    }
    
    public void setFirstFoundDate(Date firstFoundDateArg) {
        this.firstfounddate.set(firstFoundDateArg);
    }
    
    public SimpleObjectProperty<Date> firstFoundDateProperty() {
        return firstfounddate;
    }
```

This is for a javafx project.

The key for me here is how to compare an `Object` with an `Object`?

Comment: Why is `getFirstFoundDate()` declared to return an `Object` instead of... a `Date`? If you change the return type to `Date` then your second `Comparator` implementation should work (though you could siimplify it to `Comparator.comparing(ModelDefects::getFirstFoundDate)`). _Side note:_ I would strongly consider using the `java.time` API.

Comment: And actually, if you want to compare via subtraction, `getFirstFoundDate()` MUST return a numeric type.  The code you have provided in the first example won't even compile.

Comment: Let's just say for now that I want to compare `simpleobjectproperty`.  Is there a way to do it?  @JimGarrison no it definitely doesn't compile.  I'm a beginner, so I just tried a few things before coming here.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information, such as the full definition of `SimpleObjectProperty`.  We can't guess what's in your mind or in code you haven't shared.

Comment: @Slaw off the top of my head I can't remember - it was a while ago that I wrote those declarations.  It might be related to the way it's being used in JavaFX.

Comment: _"I just tried a few things before coming here"_ -- I suggest you take the [tour] and read [ask].  Coming here requires a lot more experimentation and debugging in order to ask a meaningful, answerable question.

Comment: JavaFX properties are designed to have a getter, setter, and property-getter. So if you have an `ObjectProperty<Date> foo;` field then you should have `void setFoo(Date)`, `Date getFoo()`, and `ObjectProperty<Date> fooProperty()` methods (following that naming convention, and typically all final). With that being said, I can't think of a reason why your getter would need to return `Object` instead of `Date`.

Comment: @JimGarrison Note in this case the class is `javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty`.

Comment: @JimGarrison I have spent hours trying to find an operator that works on `SimpleObjectProperty` to compare directly in that form, both by testing in the IDE and searching the web.  I'm aware that you need to try hard to figure it out before coming here and that is what I have done.  I have no idea how to `compare` this property type, despite straining to figure it out.  In the end, that's all I'm really after - what operator or other strategy works to compare this field data type.  If there is no way to compare them, then I'll move away from that data type.

Comment: @slaw I've updated the question to include getter/setter/property-getter.  I have set the getter to return data type `object` because the variable declaration is `SimpleObjectProperty`.  This is the way I learned to do it following some tutorials and reading through StackOverflow answers.  If the declared field is of type `SimpleObjectProperty`, why would you not return an `object`?

Comment: Because `SimpleObjectProperty` is generic. So what you really have is a `SimpleObjectProperty<Date>`, which means it holds a `Date` instance. You may have been slightly confused by e.g. how `SimpleBooleanProperty` is `boolean`, `SimpleDoubleProperty` is `double`, and so on. So you inferred `SimpleObjectProperty<T>` is `Object` but it's actually `T`.

Comment: @Slaw Yes that would make sense then - I definitely misunderstood that.  I just changed the return data type on the getter to `date` and changed the comparator to return `return o1.getFirstFoundDate().compareTo(o2.getFirstFoundDate())` and this seems to work.  I'll answer the question myself based on that new understanding, let me know if the answer needs any changes.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `SimpleObjectProperty` when the getter data type is set to `object`, and the getter shouldn't be set to `object` anyway.

The `SimpleObjectProperty` is actually a generic: `SimpleObjectProperty<T>` with a data type of `T`.  So in my case, changing the data type of the getter from `Object` to `Date` and modifying the comparator to read as so: `return o1.getFirstFoundDate().compareTo(o2.getFirstFoundDate())` fixed the issue.